# Sort two zipped lists in django template

Tags: python, django

On a django template is there a way to use the template tag `|dictsort:"key"` to sort a zipped list? The key belongs to the first list (object_list)

**views.py**

```
...
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    context['zipped_list'] = zip(object_list, quantity_list)
    return context
```

**some_list.html**

```
{% for obj1, obj2 in zipped_list|dictsort:"ticker" %}
{{ obj1.ticker }}
{{ obj2.quantity }}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `zipped_list` is a list of tuples which contain a dictionary in each element - e.g.

```
[
    ({'ticker': 2, 'foo': 'bar'}, {'quantity': 3, 'hello': 'world'}),
    ({'ticker': 1, 'foo': 'bar'}, {'quantity': 4, 'hello': 'world'}),
]
```

You can use the notation:

```
dictsort:"0.ticker"
```